# Visual Studio form resolution problem in editing mode

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ide, visual-studio-2019

I'm on a VB.Net Winform project and I have encountered a strange problem with my IDE Visual Studio 2019.
When I double click in the solution explorer to open the form in visual editing mode, it shows up but with a wrong resolution, the form and everything in it becomes far bigger than it should be. But when I run the project in debug mode, the runtime resolution is normal.
I do have two monitors but I never had this issue before, it would be great if someone knows why and has a solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved after a reboot. I think it was a pending windows update who caused this . Very often, a pending windows 10 update causes a problem, I've experienced the blue screen, wifi connection failure, and this time a resolution problem. Intentionally or not, it forces users to restart the computer to apply the update. Hope this can serve other people.